# zfs performance: split controller across mirrors vs splitting a mirror across controllers?

Tags: raid, zfs

Suppose I have

1. 4 disks split into 2 zfs mirrored pairs
2. 2 sata controllers, where each can take 2 disks

Obviously, better expected uptime will be achieved by splitting each controller across both mirrored pairs: so either controller can fail and still leave a (degraded) pool running on the other controller.

Suppose I care more about performance than uptime.  What is faster:

1. splitting each controller across mirrored pair
2. splitting each mirrored pair across controllers

Comment: At this small scale, I don't think it matters.

Don't overcomplicate the solution. But why are you expecting SATA controller failure?

Comment: its a toy example, in reality there are several controllers and 12 disks

Comment: Why didn't you ask about the real situation?

Comment: I see your confusion.  The question was phrased as a hypothetical ("Suppose...") because having only two mirrors and two controllers removes the  "the number of physical disks on a single controller" as a performance variable.  I posed the hypothetical so I could just get answers specifically about the effect of dividing pools between controllers or vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If performance is your top priority and you can tolerate the potential downtime and data unavailability caused by a controller failure, splitting each controller across mirrored pairs may offer better performance by leveraging increased parallelism and load balancing.